# C++ ignore input string

Tags: c++

I write this program and run it in Ubuntu.
The program skip the line `cin >> str;`, not allowed me to enter the string.
How can I fix this problem?

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio_ext.h>
using namespace std;

void func()
{
    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    string str;
    __fpurge(stdin);
    cin >> str;
    cout << "Your string: " << str << endl;
    getwchar();
}

int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        cout << "0. Exit" << endl;
        cout << "1. Enter a string" << endl;
        cout << "----------------------------" << endl;
        char ch = getwchar();
        if(ch == '0') break;
        else if(ch == '1') func();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0. Exit
1. Enter a string
----------------------------
1
Enter a string: Your string:
```

Comment: Three things: While old C and new C++ standard streams are synchronized, you really shouldn't mix C and C++ input/output. Secondly, the [`getwchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getwchar) returns a value of type `wint_t`, not a narrow-character `char`. Lastly, don't invoke private and library internal functions like `__fpurge`.

Comment: Also note that using plain `>>` by default skips leading white-space, making parts of your code irrelevant.

Comment: BTW you forgot `#include <string>`

Comment: wrong tag?  maybe visual c++.  Does not compile on *nix, g++v7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation of [__fpurge](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.bpxbd00/fpurge.htm):

> After a call to `__fpurge()`, if stream is currently reading, any data that has been read from the system but not yet presented to the application will be discarded.

So delete the statement `__fpurge(stdin);` from the `func()` function.

Comment: I tried to delete `__fpurge(stdin)` statement, but it don't work.
When I enter '1', the program immediately return `func()` 

Output: 
0. Exit 
1. Enter a string 
---------------------------- 
1 
Enter a string: Your string: 
0. Exit 
1. Enter a string 
----------------------------

Answer (score 0):

Stop purging the input. You already getwchar in the main loop, so you've already waited for the input before calling func(). Just delete

```
    __fpurge(stdin);
```

from func()